# I am trying to get messageUpdate logs but sends null instead

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to build a bot that will log if a user edit his message in a channel!

I am using the code :

```js
client.on('messageUpdate', async (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
  if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) {
    return;
  }
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setAuthor(newMessage.author)
    .setDescription(`Ένα μήνυμα του ${newMessage.author} επεργάστηκε στο κανάλι ${newMessage.channel} `)
    .addField('Παλιό Μήνυμα:', oldMessage.content, true)
    .addField('Καινούργιο Μήνυμα:', newMessage.content, true)
    
  const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'test')
  channel.send(embed);
});
```

There is no error coming with code; it sends the embed but it is not showing the message author and the old message and sends `null` instead of the message author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have mentions in the embed title. Mentions of any kind will only render correctly in field values and descriptions.

If you want to add those mentions, you can use another `.addField()` or `.setDescription()`. And you can't pass an author object to `.setAuthor()`. You can only set an author name, icon, and a URL using [`.setAuthor()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setAuthor):

```js
client.on('messageUpdate', async (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
  if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) {
    return;
  }
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setAuthor(newMessage.author.username, newMessage.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setDescription(
      `Ένα μήνυμα του ${newMessage.author} επεργάστηκε στο κανάλι ${newMessage.channel} `
    )
    .addField('Παλιό Μήνυμα:', oldMessage.content, true)
    .addField('Καινούργιο Μήνυμα:', newMessage.content, true);

  const channel = client.channels.cache.find(
    (channel) => channel.name === 'test-cat-2',
  );
  channel.send(embed);
});
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick response Mr Zsolt! I tested what you said and now i got error `Cannot read property 'username' of null` .

Comment: I did an update in my question's code . If I keep my setting in code its just send `null` for `author`

Comment: the title made to description and I added `newMessage.author` but is sends null. If I add `newMessage.author.username` sends me an error that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null`. In line `.addField('Παλιό Μήνυμα:', oldMessage.content, true)` sends me again null !

Comment: That's weird. Did these work before? I've just tried it and the code above seems to be working fine.

Comment: It is very weird. I am trying the same code and i got the error I told you above and the null thing .

Comment: Just restarded my code and everything works nice. I don't know what happended.Sorry for taking your time for no reason at the end!